# The last thumbnail picture in CSS grid doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name ='viewport' content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href = 'css/reset.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href = 'css/main.css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href = 'css/gallery.css'>

</head>
<body>
<header id="header-main">
<nav class="wrapper-main">
<a href = '#'><img scr ='img/logo' alt = 'BaileyDownsLogo'></a>
    <ul>
<li> <a href = "">News</a></li>
<li> <a href = "">Ginger Snaps Photos</a></li>
<li> <a href = "">Emily Perkins</a></li>
<li> <a href = "">Katharine Isabelle</a></li>
<li> <a href = "">Register</a></li>
<li> <a href = "">Contacts</a></li>
<li> <a href = "">Forum</a></li>

    </ul>
 </nav>

</header>

<section id = 'index-gallery' class="wrapper-gallery">

<p>Life in Bailey Downs</p>
<h2>Ginger Snaps Photos</h2>
<div class='gallery-img img1'>
<div><a href=#>Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>
<div class='gallery-img img2'>
<div><a href="#">Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>
<div class='gallery-img img3'>
<div><a href="#">Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>
<div class='gallery-img img4'>
<div><a href="#">Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>
<div class='gallery-img img5'>
<div><a href="#">Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>
<div class='gallery-img img6'>
 <div><a href="#">Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>
 <div class='gallery-img img7'>
 <div><a href="#">Brigitte Fitzgerald</a></div>
</div>


                                                                

 </section>
 <script src="js/gallery.js"></script>

 </body>

 enter code here</html>
```

```

```
#index-gallery {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p gallery-p'
    'gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2 gallery-h2'
    'img1 img2 img3 img4'
    'img5 img6 img3 img7';


}

#index-gallery .gallery-img {
   width: 100%;
   height:300px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
   cursor: pointer;

}

#index-gallery p {
    
    grid-area: gallery-p;
    
    
 }

 #index-gallery h2 {
    
    grid-area: gallery-h2;
    
    
 }



#index-gallery .img1 {
    
    grid-area: img1;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img1.jpg');
     }

 #index-gallery .img2 {
    
    grid-area: img2;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img2.jpg');
     }


 #index-gallery .img3 {
    
    grid-area: img3;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img3.jpg');
    height:610px;
    }

 #index-gallery .img4 {
    
    grid-area: img4;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img4.jpg');
    }


 #index-gallery .img5 {
    
    grid-area: img5;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img5.jpg');
    }

 #index-gallery .img6 {
    
    grid-area: img6;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img6.jpg');
    }

 #index-gallery .img7 {
    
    grid-area: img7;
    background-image: url('..img/thumbs/img7.jpg');
    height:110px;
    }
```

I'm coding this page according to this tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkLpo4shS6c&t=3870s
IDK what I've overlooked=(
I'm making an image gallery page and the last picture in the grid doesn't show up.

## I've spent hours trying to locate the problem, but I 've stuck.

## I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you use your browsers devtools inspect facility you should be able to see what problems there are. Not seeing an img would trigger the thought that the url might be wrong so the file not found for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps!
I see a small mistake where you load in the 7th image.

It needs to be:

```css
 #index-gallery .img7 {
    
    grid-area: img7;
    background-image: url('../img/thumbs/img7.jpg');
    height:110px;
    }
```

If you compare it to your code, there is a `/` missing infront of `img`.
I spotted another small mistake in your HTML file. You don't close off the last meta tag before the title tag. You are missing a `>`. So it should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's all due to my absent mindness(

Comment: You've really helpend me here!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to upvote or mark my answer as "accepted" so it can help others that have the same issue